# Add legend of geom_boxplot to legend of geom_violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following code:

```
librery(ggplot2)
ggplot( mtcars ) + 
  geom_violin(  
    aes(
      x = factor(cyl), 
      y = mpg, 
      fill = factor(cyl)
    )
  ) +   
  geom_boxplot( 
    aes( 
      x = factor(cyl),
      y = qsec,
      fill = "blue"
    ),
    width = 0.3,
    alpha = 0.4
  )
```

which produces the following graph

[image]

The plot looks fine, but I would like to have the legend differently:

- 4 to 6 only showing the colour
- 'blue' showing the boxplot symbol but no background colour and with a
  legend "boxplot qsec"

I am sure this is possible (there is everything possible with ggplot...) but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ggplot you get one legend per aesthetic, you already used fill for violins so you can use color for boxplots to make two separate legends. Specify the `fill` of boxplots outside of the `aes` and manually specify the color  in`scale_color_manual`.
Here is one approach:

```
ggplot(mtcars ) + 
  geom_violin(  
    aes(
      x = factor(cyl), 
      y = mpg, 
      fill = factor(cyl)
    )
  ) +   
  geom_boxplot( 
    aes( 
      x = factor(cyl),
      y = qsec,
      color = "blue"),
    width = 0.3,
    alpha = 0.4,
    fill = "blue"
  )+
  +
  scale_color_manual("The QSECS", labels = "text", values = "blue" ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Cylinders"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that looks very nice and clean. Following there: how can I chalge "colour" to "The QSECS" (or any other text) and the "factor(cyl) to "Cylinders"? and the legend text "blue" to any other text?

Comment: @Rainer  glad to  help, added two ways in which you can change the legend.

Comment: Adding ```labels = "other text"``` to ```scale_color_manual``` is changing the legend label.

Comment: Thanks a lot - looks perfect.